# How to find probability without being given a percentage?

Tags: statistics

The problem I am having issues with is 
"A car model has 29 MPG with standard deviation of 5 MPG. A company wants to buy 38 of these cars. What is the probability the average MPG is greater than 27.8"

I cannot for the life of me find help on this type of problem. I understand how to use the normalcdf for instance I want to say to solve this using ti83 I would.. normalcdf(27.8, 1e99, 29, 5) because 27.8 is lower bound 1e99 gets us the rest of the info (because greater than) 29 mean and 5 standard deviation but I get this problem wrong.. Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{38}$ are independent and have $\mu = E(X_i) = 29$ and $\sigma = SD(X_i) = 5$ then the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) says that
$\bar X$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and 
standard deviation (SD) $\sigma/\sqrt{38}.$

Then you seek $P(\bar X > 27.8),$ which you can evaluate by standardizing
and referring to a printed CDF table of the standard normal distribution or
by using a statistical calculator. (If using a calculator, surely you need
to "tell" it the SD of the normal distribution of $\bar X.$ It looks as if
you may be telling it the SD $\sigma$ of each observation instead.)

So you should refer to you text for information about the CLT and about
evaluating normal probabilities.

Comment: I got it! And understand now, thank you!!

Comment: @gary: Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: @BruceET: No problem.